# Matplotlib in python, using data returned from another function to plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a function that returns a list of tuples, each tuple is of the form (x, y) where x and y are numbers. I need to plot every x and y number for the whole list in a line graph. I have never used matplotlib so i am at a loss.

Comment: I suggest editing the question and better explain and pose your question

Comment: im not sure how else to put it

Answer (score 0):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x_coordinates = list()
y_coordinates = list()
.....
.....
x,y = function()
x_coordinates.append(x)
y_coordinates.append(y)
plt.plot(x_coordinates,y_coordinates)
plt.show()
```

I assume you are already using a loop to get x,y values.

I hope this answers your question.